# Expresso Store checkout: How to display custom field if checkout contains a particular category of product

Tags: expresso-store, checkout

I need to show a text area custom field inside the checkout>details just if the order contains a product with a certain category ID. How to do it?

this is the scenario:
for example, in my store i sell prints and illustrations.
(prints are shipped by post and illustrations are downlodable only)
if the details page (next step after checkout) contains an illustration (category_id XX) I want to show a text area where customer write down all specs, instructions and comments.

for other products, prints and other common items i don't want to show this custom field inside the checkout page

Please advice me! thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the checkout and order tags, you can access the `{items}` loop. Inside the `{items}` loop you can use the `{entry_id}` variable to access entry custom fields and categories:

```
{items}
  {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <!-- you can access category tags here -->
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/items}
```

Then inside the channel entries tag you can access the regular `{categories}` loop.

See:

https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#checkout_tag_variables

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#categories